# Azure App Service node deployment with patch-package module

Tags: azure-web-app-service, patch-package

I am trying to run patch-package during a Node app deployment on Azure App Services (deployed with continuous integration from BitBucket). The patch-package script works fine locally (on Mac), but fails on Azure (Windows). The patch-package module is installed in node_modules but the post-install script fails with the following error:

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd" Handling node.js
> deployment. Creating app_offline.htm KuduSync.NET from:
> 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot' Deleting
> app_offline.htm Looking for app.js/server.js under site root. Using
> start-up script app.js Generated web.config. The package.json file
> does not specify node.js engine version constraints. The node.js
> application will run with the default node.js version 14.16.0.
> Selected npm version 6.14.11
>
> my-app@1.0.0 postinstall D:\home\site\wwwroot patch-package
>
> 'patch-package' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
> errno 1 npm ERR! rs-email-yelp@1.0.0 postinstall: `patch-package` npm
> ERR! Exit status 1

And here is my (simplified) package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "patch-package": "^6.4.4",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  }
}
```

I get the same error when I try and manually run `npm i` in Kudu command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, here is what solved it for me:

-stopped the web app
-deleted the node_modules folder
-ran a new deploy from git repo (which reinstalled all modules)

Everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this with the same issue I had...

I had added `patch-package` in `devDependencies`, but Azure is running `npm i --production` so `patch-package` never got installed.

Changing `patch-package` to be in `dependencies` fixed it for me.